# I am trying to automate adding mailbox permission with variables

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to run this script to add permissions to mailboxes. If I remove all of the variables it works fine .. but I really need to be able to automate this. the code is not accepting the values I have assigned to each of the variables. guessing it ahs something to do with that the code is using a variable inside another one.

```
$MB = MAILBOX
$GR = GROUP
$PR = PERMISION 

ForEach($f in (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $MB | Where { $_.FolderPath.Contains("/") -eq $True } ) )
{
$fname = '$MB:' + $f.FolderPath.Replace("/","\"); add-MailboxFolderPermission $fname -User $GR -AccessRights $PR
Invoke-Command $fname
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
}
```

$MB Errors

```
The specified mailbox "$MB" doesn't exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=xxxxxxxx,RequestId=xxxxxxx,TimeStamp=5/31/2019
    9:50:08 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] CCB4481D,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Sto
  reTasks.AddMailboxFolderPermission
```

$GR Errors

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'User' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Add-MailboxFolderPermission
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be a huge help.
Thanks

Comment: You need to take step back and approach this one piece at a time, to make sure you are getting back what you expect at each stage, and as such being able to pass / use at other stages in the script. The error is pretty specific. The specified mailbox "$MB" doesn't exist'. All else is moot until that is resolved.

Comment: You can start by not using single-quotes around `'$MB:'`, Like this, you are not expanding whatever is inside the `$MB` variable, but instead use it as a literal string.

Comment: I'd change the line `$fname = '$MB:' + $f.FolderPath.Replace("/","\")` into `$fname = '{0}:\{1}' -f $MB, $f.FolderPath.Replace("/","\")`. What is the purpose of `Invoke-Command $fname` ?? $fname is not a scriptblock, just an identifier string for the `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` cmdlet.